# Closed form solution for $1 - \left(\frac{n-x}{n+1}\right)^n = \left(\frac{n(x+1)}{n+1}\right)^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I was looking for a closed form solution to $$1 - \left(\frac{n-x}{n+1}\right)^n = \left(\frac{n(x+1)}{n+1}\right)^n,$$
Where we fix a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and want to find some $x \in (-1, n).$ I know there exists exactly one solution for all $n$, but I was wondering if anyone had any ideas/tricks to find the closed form solution for some particular $n$. If it is helpful, the limit as $n\to\infty$ has $x\to0$ as a solution and the value is $1 - \frac{1}{e}$. Furthermore, if we extend $n$ to be negative we get that as $n\to-1: x\to -1$ is a solution and the value is $1 - \phi$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

So far, I have shown also that the solution for any $x$ lies between $\left(0, \frac1n\right]$. If anyone has experienced a similar problem and could also direct me to any papers those would be very much appreciated.

Please let me know if you have any ideas. Everything helps. Thank you so much for your taking your time to read this.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the specific question you are asking? Not clear to me

Comment: Is the numerator on the right-hand side $x+1$, $(x+1)^n$ or $n(x+1)$? Asking because the expression on the LHS is quite different from the expression on the RHS, I wonder if it is intentional or a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that, for $n>0$, you look for the zero of function
$$f_n(x)=  \left(\frac{n(x+1)}{n+1}\right)^n+\left(\frac{n-x}{n+1}\right)^n -1$$ you can obtain good and explicit *approximations* of the solution using $\color{red}{\text{the first iterate } x_1}$ of  any Newton-like method starting with $x_0=\frac 1{2n}$ which is the mid point of the range you properly found.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
n & \text{Newton} & \text{Halley} & \text{Householder} & \text{solution}\\
 2 &  0.20192307692  &  0.20007680492 &   0.20000307201 &  0.20000000001 \\
 3 &  0.14786159467  &  0.14742915877 &   0.14742113081 &  0.14742098978 \\
 4 &  0.11640467089  &  0.11628024514 &   0.11627903269 &  0.11627902258 \\
 5 &  0.09591899676  &  0.09588305657 &   0.09588286839 &  0.09588286762 \\
 6 &  0.08154173322  &  0.08153326724 &   0.08153324548 &  0.08153324563 \\
 7 &  0.07090308560  &  0.07090222401 &   0.07090222329 &  0.07090222329 \\
 8 &  0.06271554490  &  0.06271537743 &   0.06271537749 &  0.06271537749 \\
 9 &  0.05622081012  &  0.05621899986 &   0.05621900215 &  0.05621900216 \\
 10 & 0.05094369255  &  0.05093961650 &   0.05093962441 &  0.05093962448 \\
15 &  0.03466687967 &  0.03465440239 & 
   0.03465444977 &  0.03465445080 \\
 20 &  0.02627067957 &  0.02625540494 & 
   0.02625547564 &  0.02625547775 \\
 25 &  0.02114808974 &  0.02113239644 & 
   0.02113247642 &  0.02113247926 \\
 30 &  0.01769709234 &  0.01768185314 & 
   0.01768193537 &  0.01768193528 \\
 35 &  0.01521430619 &  0.01519982012 & 
   0.01519990129 &  0.01519990122 \\
 40 &  0.01334241629 &  0.01332875729 & 
   0.01332883591 &  0.01332883584 \\
 45 &  0.01188066213 &  0.01186781431 & 
   0.01186788976 &  0.01186788970 \\
 50 &  0.01070756392 &  0.01069547703 & 
   0.01069554913 &  0.01069554908 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

We could do better onsidering instead that we look for the zero of function
$$g_n(x)=\log\left(  \left(\frac{n(x+1)}{n+1}\right)^n+\left(\frac{n-x}{n+1}\right)^n\right) $$ which is more linear than $f(x)$.

Expanding as series around $x=0$ gives
$$g(x)=\log \left(2 \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\right)+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(n-1)\,P_k(n)}{a_k\,\,n^{k-1}}x^k $$ where the first coefficients $a_k$ form the (unknown) sequence
$$\{1,4,12,96,240,2880,6720,322560,80640,14515200\}$$
The very first polynomials $P_k(n)$ being
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & P_k(n) \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & n^2+n+2 \\
 3 & -3 n^3-2 n^2+n+4 \\
 4 & -n^6-5 n^5+11 n^4-n^3-14 n^2+2 n+24 \\
 5 & 5 n^7+20 n^6-20 n^5-12 n^4-7 n^3-32 n^2-2 n+48 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ We can generate as many terms as required and, using [power series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) with the explicit formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ term given by Morse and Feshbach, we could find the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $-1<x<n\in\Bbb N$ is wanted, define $x=\sqrt[n]w-1$ and use [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem):

$$w=\left(\frac1n+1\right)^n-\left(\frac1n+1-\frac{\sqrt[n]w} n\right)^n\implies x=\frac 1n+\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\left.\frac{d^{k-1}}{dw^{k-1}}w^{\frac1n-1}\left(\frac1n+1-\frac{\sqrt[n]w}n\right)^{nk}\right|_{\left(\frac1n+1\right)^n}$$

Binomial series gives

$$\frac{d^{k-1}}{dw^{k-1}}w^{\frac1n-1}\left(\frac1n+1-\frac{\sqrt[n]w}n\right)^{nk}=\sum_{m=0}^{nk}\binom{nk}m \left(\frac1n+1\right)^m \left(-\frac1n\right)^{kn-m}\frac{d^{k-1}}{dw^{k-1}}w^{k+\frac{1-m}n-1}$$

where [factorial power $u^{(v)}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factorialpower) appears. Therefore:

$$\bbox[4px,border: 5px ridge #AECCE4 ]{1 - \left(\frac{n-x}{n+1}\right)^n = \left(\frac{n(x+1)}{n+1}\right)^n \implies x=\frac1n+\frac1n\left(\frac1n+1\right)\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^{nk}\binom{nk}m\left(\frac{1-m}n+k-1\right)^{(k-1)}\frac{(-1)^{m+(n-1)k}n^{m-nk}}{k!}}$$

[shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F4%2B%281%2F4%29%281%2F4%2B1%29+sum%5Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5E%28m%2B3k%29%2Fk%21+binom%284+k%2Cm%29++4%5E%28m-4+k%29++factorialpower%28%28-1+%2B+%281-m%29%2F4+%2B+k+%29%2C+-1+%2B+k%29%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C300%7D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C20%7D%5D) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1-%28%284-x%29%2F%284%2B1%29%29%5E4%3D%284+%28x%2B1%29%2F%284%2B1%29%29%5E4). If $k$ goes up to $\infty$, then both sums are interchangeable. Just maybe one can use the [Gauss multiplication formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussMultiplicationFormula.html) and [double hypergeometric series function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KampedeFerietFunction.html) for a “closed form”. The [Fox wright function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function), a special case of [Fox H](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoxH.html) gives

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac1n-\frac mn\right)\Gamma(1+kn) \left(-(-n)^{-n}\right)^k(-n)^m}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac1n-\frac mn\right)\Gamma(1-m+kn)m!k!}= \frac{\Gamma(1+kn) \left(-(-n)^{-n}\right)^k}{k!}\,_1\Psi_2\left(^{\qquad\left(k+\frac1n,-\frac1n\right)}_{\left(1+\frac1n,-\frac1n\right),(1+kn,-1)};-n\right)$$

so

$$\bbox[4px,border: 5px ridge #AECCE4 ]{1 - \left(\frac{n-x}{n+1}\right)^n = \left(\frac{n(x+1)}{n+1}\right)^n \implies x=\frac1n+\frac1n\left(\frac1n+1\right)\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k (-n)^{-kn}(kn)!}{k!}\,_1\Psi_2\left(^{\qquad\left(k+\frac1n,-\frac1n\right)}_{\left(1+\frac1n,-\frac1n\right),(1+kn,-1)};-n\right)}$$

Comment: The $n=1,\dots, 5$ cases have closed forms

Comment: @BraydenLetwin For $n$, you need the root of an $n-1$ degree polynomial. There are closed forms for degree $n-1$ polynomials mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406250/transcendental-formulas-for-roots-of-polynomials), but they are hard/complicated to use.

Comment: Sorry; I meant to link [this mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23094/method-of-finding-roots-of-polynominal-equations-with-arithmetic-operations-and)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146787/discussion-between-tyma-gaidash-and-brayden-letwin).